# Ubuntu driving 4K LG TV (55UF7600)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

I have a laptop that is capable of driving 4K screens (drives a 2K screen regularly).  I'm trying, without success, to get it to drive a 4K TV (LG 55UF7600) through a Display Port out to an HDMI in (both are capable of 4K transmissions).  However, Ubuntu only offers 1080p as the max resolution it will drive on the TV (through `nvidia-settings` and `Settings` -> `Display`).  I'm puzzled as to why.

I've done some reading and tried to force X to send by creating a "10-monitor.conf" file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`.  However, that didn't work.  The file contains:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -HSync +VSync
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "DP-0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "3840x2160" "1920x1080"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I generated the `Modeline` using:

```
cvt 3840 2160 60
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

Before creating the `10-monitor.conf` file, I tried adding the mode with `xrandr`:

```
    xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -HSync +VSync
    xrandr --addmode DP-0 3840x2160_60.00
    X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
        Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
        Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
        Serial number of failed request:  45
        Current serial number in output stream:  46
```

I couldn't figure out that error message (it isn't exactly helpful to the uninitiated).

Here are the interesting messages I found in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[   341.357] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[   341.357] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics LG TV (DFP-0) (Using EDID
[   341.357] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for LG Electronics LG TV (DFP-0) contradicts itself:
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (58.000-62.000 Hz) would
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (30.0 Hz); ignoring
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     VertRefresh check for mode "1920x1080".
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for LG Electronics LG TV (DFP-0) contradicts itself:
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     EDID's valid HorizSync range (30.000-83.000 kHz) would
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     exclude this mode's HorizSync (27.0 kHz); ignoring
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     HorizSync check for mode "1920x1080".
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for LG Electronics LG TV (DFP-0) contradicts itself:
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (58.000-62.000 Hz) would
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (24.0 Hz); ignoring
[   341.358] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     VertRefresh check for mode "1920x1080".
[   369.265] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[   369.535] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
```

My guess is that the TV is sending the wrong EDID, claiming to only support 1080p.  I tried adding this option to my `10-monitor.conf` file:

```
Option "UseEDID" "FALSE"
```

But this just killed X.  It wouldn't start at all (blue screen, no login).

I tried using get/parse-edid software, but I must not be using it correctly because I couldn't get any EDIDs.

For completeness sake, my xrandr output is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     30.0     24.0     60.1     60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   40.0  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x335)  712.8MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  134.2KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock   60.0Hz
smm@smmlaptop:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ xrandr --addmode DP-0 3840x2160_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
smm@smmlaptop:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     30.0     24.0     60.1     60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   40.0  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x335)  712.8MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  134.2KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock   60.0Hz
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried 3840x2160 at 30 hz?
This was the maximum under HDMI 1.4. I am having the same problem as you with nvidia on WinXP and a new TCL TV.
I also suspect the EDID. I am about to install ubuntu server hoping this will help me solve the issue.

Comment: I haven't worked on the problem recently (having other problems with LG - updating the firmware broken WiDi/Miracast and LG doesn't support it).  Make sure you get it figured out before the return period for the TV is past.  LG refuses to support their products, so if it doesn't work now, it probably won't ever.

Answer (score -2):

I have a 55" 4K Samsung TV and a Acer 4K portable computer both with a hdmi port.
I have two different HDMI cables. It didn't work with one, but worked perfectly with the other. Just try to change to a better cable.

Comment: Sounds like you have a defective cable.  Please read http://www.cnet.com/news/why-all-hdmi-cables-are-the-same/ to understand why there a no "better" cables.

Comment: Your answer does not specifically answer the OPs question. Please be specific and improve your answer if possible.